# 'Access violation' error message while uploading files

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I'm using CCK FileField (and CCK VideoField) in my content-type.

I get 'Access violation' error message (after several minutes uploading) when I upload big videos (let's say.. 18MB). (The Access violation is a server message I guess.. or PHP error message..

My PHP Post max size is 100M so I guess this is not the issue.

What could be the reason ?
Is a file permissions issues ? They should be 777 on all files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time`, in php.ini? It could be that your connection/script times out before you have uploaded all your data.